# Prefix elements of string array with key in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have a 2 jsons with its environment and the applications in it.
To compare the different (missing applications) between the 2 json,
I want to simplify the json in to an array, so that I can use minus to find the different,
but I failed to set the key as a prefix of the array.

example input:

```
{
  "qa": [
    "app-a",
    "app-b",
    "app-c"
  ],
  "prod": [
    "app-a",
    "app-c",
    "app-e"
  ]
}
```

expected output:

```
[
  "qa:app-a",
  "qa:app-b",
  "qa:app-c",
  "prod:app-a",
  "prod:app-c",
  "prod:app-e",
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
to_entries | map(.key + ":" + .value[])
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wcZFvf6IOSO)</sup>